# how does solr detect multivalue fields

Tags: solr

I'm trying to index data using solr. In the managment-shema I define a field multi value to false, so when I post data I get error telling that  `multiple values encountered for non multiValued field`.
so what I want to understand is how does solr detect a multi value field,
 for example: if I have this phrase `aa bb cc dd` and I want to index/store it as a single value, why does solr refuse it .
I also made some tests using Analysis in the admin console, and I found that if the phrase contains:' , ' ' ' or '/' solr consider it to be multiple value, so I guess that there is a file where it is define how solr detect multiple value. 
thank you in advance 
**edit**
here is the field that cause the problem, from my managed-shema : 
`<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" .multiValued="false"/>`

Comment: can you show us an example of a documetn that causes that error?
It should only be considered multivalue if you have something like:
``  <field name="A"> aa bb</field>
  <field name="A">cc dd</field>
``

Comment: I'm using the films.json example given by solr, and here is the line that causes the problem :"name": "\"Weird Al\" Yankovic: The Ultimate Video Collection".

Comment: Can you show how is the schema for the field that is giving that error? by looking at films.json it shouldn't consider it multivalued.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing multiValued fields and the text tokenization process.

Multivalued field is when your client provides a list of values to Solr. They are treated as distinct and are returned in array structure.

The analysis screen of the Admin UI shows you the tokenization process, which is what makes search engine work. Fields have stored (original) representation as well as the indexed one. The indexed one (as shown by the Analysis UI) is processed version to enable fast search.

So, a value "aa bb cc dd" if sent as a string to a text_general field, will be stored as one value, but indexed as tokens **aa**, **bb**, **cc**, and **dd**, which then allows you to search for **cc** and find it.

Comment: you were right, I had a misunderstand of that part, but how can solr detect mutivalued fields ??, and another thing, what is the difference in indexing and storing of a phrase, for example, **aa bb cc  dd** if it is multivalued or not